# Having a file pathname as a starting input of a Python program

Tags: python, windows

Just for fun, I tried to make a shortcut for the "java -jar filepathname" command on the Windows prompt.

```
import os
import time


def getJarFileName(pathName):
    jarFileName = ""

    for i in range(0, len(pathName)):
        if (pathName[i] == "\\"):
            jarFileName = ""
        else:
            jarFileName += pathName[i]

    return jarFileName

jarFound = False

while (jarFound == False):
    jarPathName = input("Insert a *.jar file pathname to execute:\n")

    if not (jarPathName.endswith(".jar")):
        jarPathName += ".jar"

    if (os.access(jarPathName, os.R_OK)): 
        os.system('cls')
        os.system("java -jar " + jarPathName)
        jarFound = True

        print("\n| \"%s\" terminated. |" % getJarFileName(jarPathName))
        time.sleep(1)

    else:
        print("\n| \"%s\" not found. |\n" % getJarFileName(jarPathName))
```

This works wonderfully, but I'd like to skip the input process, and basically be able to directly open .jar files with this program (maybe by dropping jar files on this launcher's icon, and stuff like that). I searched all evening for something like this, but I couldn't find anything. Is what I want to do even possible? Thanks in advance for your help.

NB: I know that there are other more convenient ways to open .jar files, I'm just playing around with this kinds of things.

Comment: Have a look at `sys.argv`.

Comment: Great, this did the trick. Thank you very much!